# Redis read from multiple streams using a single client connection

Tags: redis, redis-cluster

I'm using Redis server v=6.2.6 with 3 masters and 2 slaves for each master, hence total 9 nodes in the cluster.

I have 2 streams with some records in those streams. When I try to read from both the streams from redis-cli as:

```
xread STREAMS mystream stream02 0 0
```

I see the error message:

> (error) CROSSSLOT Keys in request don't hash to the same slot

Does it mean that practically we cannot read records from multiple streams in a single connection if the keys (stream names/id) hash to different owner/master nodes?

Isn't this very limiting?
What is the supposed way to consume records from multiple streams in a single client?